# Export 2D image from 3D FBX file — Thumbnail generator

Tags: open-source, 3d, thumbnail

I am looking for a tool that will allow me programatically generate 2D thumbnails in the form of JPGs or PNGs from 3D objects specifically in FBX format.

Microsoft 3D Viewer for example has an "Export Image" feature that allows me to manually create a 2D image from a 3D object. However, I need a programatic solution to automatically generate thumbnails of 3D objects for a web application I am developing.

Python scripts, NodeJS scripts, or any executable would be handy.

[image: ort,]

Comment: Hi @Syed! Did you finally manage how to do it?